# How to use "var" and "palette" together in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, point, var, palette

gnuplot script:

```
set xrange [25:60]
set yrange [45:80]
set palette defined(1 "red", 2 "green", 3 "blue")
unset key
unset colorbox
plot 'test.data' using 1:2:3:4 with points pt 7 ps var lt palette
```

test.data

```
x       y       count   color
30      50      4       1
35      55      3       1
40      60      2       2
45      65      5       2
50      70      4       3
55      75      2       3
```

output:
[image]

I need so:
[image]

How to use "var" and "palette" together in gnuplot?

*gnuplot Version 4.4 patchlevel 3*

Comment: Any chance you could do with gnuplot 4.6? You get the desired result with that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the autoscaling of the color range doesn't work properly in this case with version 4.4.3 (with 4.6.5 your script works out of the box). Also using `set autoscale cbfix` doesn't works as it seems to use the values of the third column for the scaling. (comment out `unset colorbox` to see this).

If you explicitely set a color range, it works fine also with 4.4.3:

```
set xrange [25:60]
set yrange [45:80]

set cbrange [1:3]    

set palette defined(1 "red", 2 "green", 3 "blue")
unset key
unset colorbox
plot 'test.data' using 1:2:3:4 with points pt 7 ps var lt palette
```